# How to publish my Google Business reviews updates to my topic

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub, google-my-business-api

Using the Google Cloud Platform I would like trigger a Cloud Compute function when a new review to send data to a third party system.

I have created the function that sends notications to my third party endpoint, however I am struggling hooking this into when Reviews are added to my business page.

Here's what I've done so far:

1. Create topic called "new-google-review"
2. Created subscription under topic called "new-updated-reviews"

The subscription is set to PUSH to the following endpoint URL descibed by the [docs](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest/v4/accounts/updateNotifications):
[https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/{name=accounts/*/notifications}](https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/%7Bname=accounts/*/notifications%7D)

I'm not sure if this is quite correct, and I'm struggling to understand the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The `accounts.updateNotifications` is an administrative API you use to set up the notification, it is not the push endpoint you use for your subscription. The process you would use to set up this type of notification would be:

1. Create a Pub/Sub topic. Let's say it is `projects/my-project/topics/my-topic`.
2. Create a [Cloud Function with a Pub/Sub trigger](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/pubsub). You can do this in the [Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/functions/add). Choose "Cloud Pub/Sub" as the trigger type and choose the topic you created in step 1 as the topic. This will create a push subscription that triggers the Cloud Function every time a message comes through.
3. Make a request to `https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts/{accountId}/notifications` with a [`Notifications`](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest/v4/Notifications) object as the body, where `acccountId` is your account ID. The `topicName` would be the topic name created in step 1 (in this example, `projects/my-project/topics/my-topic`) and the `notificationTypes` would be a list containing the single item `NEW_REVIEW`. You could do this as a `curl` request, e.g.,:

```
curl -X https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts/{accountId}/notifications -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"name": "my-name","topicName": "projects/my-project/topics/my-topic","notificationTypes": ["NEW_REVIEW"]}'
```

though you will need to be authenticated to make that request.

If that call returns successfully, then it means that your notification has been set up properly and your Cloud Function should now trigger every time you get a new review.